# What does deleting a file really do?

Tags: security, file-system, delete

When I run an app, select a file, and choose "delete" what happens then:

1. the file is moved to trash (and later is removed by OS when some conditions are met)
2. the file is removed from the filesystem at once
3. (1) or (2) depending on an app

?

Comment: Obviously it depends on the app. A "delete" button in an app might do anything or nothing. It would be a lot easier to give a meaningful answer if you'd [edit] your question to say what's the particular problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @DanHulme, thank you. One note -- if you say "it depends on the app" it implies that Android OS supports the Trash mechanism (if not, there would be no chance of postponed removal). My problem -- I simply want to be aware (want to know) how the deletion of the file is handled for security reasons. IOW -- is undeleting is as simple as browsing through (hidden or not) Trash content, or does it take something more sophisticated like recreating files from some raw data dump.

Comment: That also depends on the app. The Trash feature you mentioned is Windows Explorer feature. Which is also kind of an app. Other Windows programs may or may not use the trash either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no OS-wide "Trash" or "Recycle bin" like other shells have. However, the Android design guidelines recommend app authors to put something like that in each app as appropriate, to allow undoing deletes. Thus, in one app, a delete button might delete the content immediately, while another might mark the content as deleted but wait for some time before deleting any files in the filesystem.

There are even more possibilities with apps that sync to a server: they might need to keep 'deleted' content around for the next sync, or it might be on a server somewhere, never deleted.

In addition, not every item of user data you might delete is a file. Some apps might store things in a database, so after you delete an item, part or all of it might still be present in the app's database.

Of course, like any filesystem, once a file is deleted, most of its content remains on the storage. Someone with physical access to the storage, or a rogue [root](/questions/tagged/root) app, can almost certainly still read it for quite some time after it's deleted. It's pretty easy to recover files in this way, especially if your phone acts as a *USB mass storage* device when plugged into a computer.